# Counting array in API JSON Response

Tags: php, arrays, json, stripe-payments

I'm trying to do a simple count of how many refunds are in my Stripe Response but `count()` isn't working and I don't really know any other way of achieving this.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
$retrieve_event =  Stripe_Event::retrieve("evt_00000000000000");
$event_json_id = json_decode($retrieve_event);

$refund_array = $event_json_id->{'data'}->{'object'}->{'refunds'};
die(count($refund_array));
```

This is the response of `$retrieve_event`

```
{
  "created": 1326853478,
  "livemode": false,
  "id": "evt_00000000000000",
  "type": "charge.refunded",
  "object": "event",
  "request": null,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "ch_00000000000000",
      "object": "charge",
      "created": 1402433517,
      "livemode": false,
      "paid": true,
      "amount": 1000,
      "currency": "usd",
      "refunded": true,
      "card": {
        "id": "card_00000000000000",
        "object": "card",
        "last4": "0028",
        "type": "Visa",
        "exp_month": 8,
        "exp_year": 2015,
        "fingerprint": "a5KWlTcrmCYk5DIYa",
        "country": "US",
        "name": "First Last",
        "address_line1": "null",
        "address_line2": null,
        "address_city": "null",
        "address_state": "null",
        "address_zip": "null",
        "address_country": "US",
        "cvc_check": null,
        "address_line1_check": "fail",
        "address_zip_check": "pass",
        "customer": "cus_00000000000000"
      },
      "captured": true,
      "refunds": [
        {
          "id": "re_104CKt4uGeYuVLAahMwLA2TK",
          "amount": 100,
          "currency": "usd",
          "created": 1402433533,
          "object": "refund",
          "charge": "ch_104CKt4uGeYuVLAazSyPqqLV",
          "balance_transaction": "txn_104CKt4uGeYuVLAaSNZCR867",
          "metadata": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "re_104CKt4uGeYuVLAaDIMHoIos",
          "amount": 200,
          "currency": "usd",
          "created": 1402433539,
          "object": "refund",
          "charge": "ch_104CKt4uGeYuVLAazSyPqqLV",
          "balance_transaction": "txn_104CKt4uGeYuVLAaqSwkNKPO",
          "metadata": {}
        },
        {
          "id": "re_4CL6n1r91dY5ME",
          "amount": 700,
          "currency": "usd",
          "created": 1402434306,
          "object": "refund",
          "charge": "ch_4CL6FNWhGzVuAV",
          "balance_transaction": "txn_4CL6qa4vwlVaDJ"
        }
      ],
      "balance_transaction": "txn_00000000000000",
      "failure_message": null,
      "failure_code": null,
      "amount_refunded": 1000,
      "customer": "cus_00000000000000",
      "invoice": null,
      "description": "this is a description",
      "dispute": null,
      "metadata": {},
      "statement_description": "this is a description",
      "fee": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Count works for me... `var_dump(count($string->data->object->refunds));`

Comment: Have a look: http://codepad.viper-7.com/90hYqn

Comment: Thanks @Farkie, I was just doing `count($refund_array)` and not encasing it with `var_dump()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the way you're trying to output the count. [This example outputs `3`](https://eval.in/160774):

```
echo count($refund_array);
exit;
```

[Whereas this example doesn't](https://eval.in/160773):

```
die(count($refund_array));
```

The reason is because you're simply passing in an integer into `die()`. [From the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php):

> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0 is used to terminate the program successfully.

[This example](https://eval.in/160775) works because the message is a string:

```
die('Count: ' . count($refund_array)); // Count: 3
```

...or:

```
die((string) count($refund_array));    // 3
```

Comment: Wow, thanks @Scrowler! Why would die make it not work?

Comment: `die` acts differently depending on whether the argument is a number or string.

Comment: @scrowler Stripe has released new version, which gives refund count in `total_count` parameter in refunds Object.

Answer (score 1):

The `count()` just needs to be cast as a string:

```
die((string) count($refund_array));
```

Answer (score 1):

As per new version of Stripe API which was released on [2014-06-17](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2014-06-17), Refunds object is modified for `Charges` Method.

Now you can directly get refund count using `total_count` parameter in refunds object.

> data->object->refund->total_count

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the update. I appreciate it.